# How do I set a timeout with millisecond accuracy in Lua?

Tags: lua

when I try to set a timeout in Lua like this:

```
function wait(seconds)
    local start = os.time()
    repeat until os.time() > start + seconds
end
```

it is too inconsistent. Is there a more precise way to set a timeout that will consistently wait for the amount of time requested?

Comment: How "consistent" does it need to be? Technically, unless you're the OS, you *can't* ensure consistency in any such thing, since the OS can just yank your timeslice whenever it wants.

Comment: Think about @Piglet last sentence in his answer. - Sleeping can push up your CPU core/s up to 100% for example 10s sleeping - Short sleeping makes them peak - Dont do sleepings for a long time period of time or your cpu fan(s) starts to singing like a jet propulsion ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using external libraries, in Lua there are basically only two ways to get higher  accuracy.

1. use `os.clock`
2. run a loop and find out how many iterations take how much time

As Nicol pointed out both will be inconsistent and unrealiable in a non real-time OS like Windows.

If your OS for whatever reason decides to clock your CPU down or to do some other crap in the background your doomed.

So think about your application and decide wether you should do it on a non-real-time OS.

Comment: Thanks! Using os.clock worked better than what I had. This is happening for about a second or so, so even 0.3s range was pretty significant. This is much better!

Answer (score 0):

On a machine where you can compile own stuff theres a way to build a sleep and msleep that dont eats up any cpu time...
Look: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_lua_calls_c.htm
...for: Make an msleep() Function